HTML Bundler Webpack Plugin - Keep Assets Directory Structure Problem
I am using HTML Bundler Webpack Plugin and following the documentation to keep the directory structure for assets: https://github.com/webdiscus/html-bundler-webpack-plugin?tab=readme-ov-file#how-to-keep-source-directory-structure-for-assets.
I've used this plugin in one other project and was able to keep the directory structure but it's not working this time. I have:
- src
  - assets
    - imgs
      - icons
      - weather-icons

The plugin is only outputting:
- dist
  - assets
    - imgs
      - icons

It's as if the weather-icons folder doesn't exist.
This is in my config:
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|ico|webp|avif|svg|)$/,
        type: "asset/resource",
        generator: {
          filename: ({ filename }) => {
            // Keep directory structure for images in dist folder
            const srcPath =
              "src/assets/imgs";

            const regExp = new RegExp(
              `[\\\\/]?(?:${path.normalize(srcPath)}|node_modules)[\\\\/](.+?)$`
            );
            const assetPath = path.dirname(
              regExp.exec(filename)[1].replace("@", "").replace(/\\/g, "/")
            );

            return `imgs/${assetPath}/[name].[contenthash:8][ext]`;
          },
        },
      },

In a previous project I had the same problem with the bundle not including my assets/imgs subfolders so I included multiple paths in srcPath, like this:
 const srcPath =
              "src/assets/imgs" ||
              "src/assets/imgs/icons" ||
              "src/assets/imgs/weather-icons";

This solution fixed the problem in my other project, however, it is not working for me on this project and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've compared my configs/syntax for the two projects and they're the same.
If it's useful, here is my entire webpack config for this project:
const path = require("path");
const HtmlBundlerPlugin = require("html-bundler-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  stats: { children: true },
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist/"),
    clean: true,
  },

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@scripts": path.join(__dirname, "src/js"),
      "@styles": path.join(__dirname, "src/styles"),
      "@images": path.join(__dirname, "src/assets/imgs"),
    },
  },

  devtool: "source-map",

  plugins: [
    new HtmlBundlerPlugin({
      entry: [
        {
          import: "./src/views/index.html", 
          filename: "index.html", 
          data: {
            title: "Weather App",
          }, 
        },
      ],

      js: {
        // output filename for JS
        filename: "js/[name].[contenthash:8].js",
      },

      css: {
        // output filename for CSS
        filename: "css/[name].[contenthash:8].css",
      },
    }),
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              import: false, 
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|ico|webp|avif|svg|)$/,
        type: "asset/resource",
        generator: {
          filename: ({ filename }) => {
            const srcPath =
              "./src/assets/imgs" ||
              "./src/assets/imgs/icons" ||
              "./src/assets/imgs/weather-icons";

            const regExp = new RegExp(
              `[\\\\/]?(?:${path.normalize(srcPath)}|node_modules)[\\\\/](.+?)$`
            );
            const assetPath = path.dirname(
              regExp.exec(filename)[1].replace("@", "").replace(/\\/g, "/")
            );

            return `imgs/${assetPath}/[name].[contenthash:8][ext]`;
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  devServer: {
    static: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    watchFiles: {
      paths: ["src/**/*.*"],
      options: {
        usePolling: true,
      },
    },
  },
};

I thought maybe something was wrong with the weather-icons folder itself so I removed it from my repo and re-added it, but that didn't fix the problem. All of the files in the subdirectories of my imgs directory are in .svg format.
I've tried searching for this problem but none of the solutions I've found about keeping directory structure are specific to the HTML Bunder Webpack Plugin.
Am I missing anything to make this work? Thanks.

Follow up: I think the problem is with the .svg files. I moved one of them from the src/assets/imgs/weather-icons directory to src/assets/imgs/icons since it's bundling correctly, but the file didn't make it into the bundle. I'm using the icons available from Visual Crossing: https://www.visualcrossing.com/resources/documentation/weather-api/defining-icon-set-in-the-weather-api/?gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiArby5BhCDARIsAIJvjISq3sCz8lRvWRxvclzosPiE3VhPIHSRTvvcnRMFN_4VZJRYCbKnUzAaAgPaEALw_wcB. Now searching for known probs with .svg and webpack but haven't found much yet. Has anyone run into this?

I no longer think the svg files are the problem. I saved one as a png and webpack wouldn't output it into the bundle. Then I tried an icon from a free svg site and that wouldn't bundle either. I'm at a complete loss as to why I can't get anything other than my github logo svg file (which is in the src/assets/imgs/icons directory) to bundle in my images directory.

please create a small repo on GitHub with reproducible issue, then I can help you. You can open an issue directly here: https://github.com/webdiscus/html-bundler-webpack-plugin/issues

Thank you, I submitted the issue on the link you provided.

The problem was in the weather-icons.js file:
const clearDay = new Image();
clearDay.src =
  "/Users/jguneratne/repos/weather-app/src/assets/imgs/weather-icons/clear-day.svg";

This image file used in new Image() will not be processed via Webpack.
You should use the require() function:
export const weatherIconsData = {
  "clear-day": require("@images/weather-icons/clear-day.svg"),
  ...
}

where @images is the Webpack alias to the images directory.
